# facebook buck & NDK issues

Tags: android, android-ndk, buck

i am new to buck, but i am trying to getbuck running (because i wanted to start working with nuclide).

Well, wenn i try to run `buck --version`it already gives me this output.

```
BUILD FAILED: Failed to read NDK version from /Users/mlostek/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle
```

The content of the `/Users/mlostek/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/source.properties`

```
Pkg.Desc = Android NDK
Pkg.Revision = 12.1.2977051
```

And

```
echo $ANDROID_NDK
/Users/mlostek/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle
```

By the way, i have installed the NDK via android studio, not via brew! And `brew doctor` says it's all fine out there.

#### UPDATE1

When i run `brew install --HEAD buck` then the logfile of the buck build tells me the following (ant build runs fine)

```
2016-08-08 12:30:13 +0200

./bin/buck
build
buck

Not using buckd because watchman isn't installed.
[2016-08-08 12:30:20.756][error][command:null][tid:01][com.facebook.buck.cli.Main] Uncaught exception at top level
java.lang.IllegalStateException: /Users/mlostek/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:174)
    at com.facebook.buck.android.NdkCxxPlatforms.getToolPath(NdkCxxPlatforms.java:577)
    at com.facebook.buck.android.NdkCxxPlatforms.getCTool(NdkCxxPlatforms.java:626)
    at com.facebook.buck.android.NdkCxxPlatforms.build(NdkCxxPlatforms.java:378)
    at com.facebook.buck.android.NdkCxxPlatforms.getPlatforms(NdkCxxPlatforms.java:137)
    at com.facebook.buck.android.NdkCxxPlatforms.getPlatforms(NdkCxxPlatforms.java:101)
    at com.facebook.buck.rules.KnownBuildRuleTypes.createBuilder(KnownBuildRuleTypes.java:339)
    at com.facebook.buck.rules.KnownBuildRuleTypes.createInstance(KnownBuildRuleTypes.java:233)
    at com.facebook.buck.rules.KnownBuildRuleTypesFactory.create(KnownBuildRuleTypesFactory.java:48)
    at com.facebook.buck.rules.Cell.<init>(Cell.java:115)
    at com.facebook.buck.rules.Cell.createCell(Cell.java:159)
    at com.facebook.buck.cli.Main.runMainWithExitCode(Main.java:829)
    at com.facebook.buck.cli.Main.runMainThenExit(Main.java:610)
    at com.facebook.buck.cli.Main.main(Main.java:1679)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.facebook.buck.cli.bootstrapper.ClassLoaderBootstrapper.main(ClassLoaderBootstrapper.java:62)


HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.9
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew.git
HEAD: 850db4ebf473738ffba8424065d62954d3c95dd1
Last commit: 35 minutes ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: c6756fa5bfe3ed5881831398ae98cf6190cdd317
Core tap last commit: 10 minutes ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
HOMEBREW_BOTTLE_DOMAIN: https://homebrew.bintray.com
CPU: quad-core 64-bit broadwell
Homebrew Ruby: 2.0.0-p648
GCC-4.2: build 0
Clang: 7.3 build 703
Git: 2.7.4 => /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git
Perl: /usr/bin/perl
Python: /usr/bin/python
Ruby: /usr/bin/ruby => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
Java: 1.8.0_66, 1.6.0_65-b14-468
OS X: 10.11.6-x86_64
Xcode: 7.3.1
CLT: 7.3.1.0.1.1461711523
X11: N/A

HOMEBREW_CC: clang
HOMEBREW_CXX: clang++
CFLAGS: -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_66.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_66.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin
CXXFLAGS: -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_66.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_66.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin
SDKROOT: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk
MAKEFLAGS: -j4
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /usr/local
CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH: /usr/include/libxml2:/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers
CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/Current/Libraries
MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET: 10.11
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR: /usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/pkgconfig/10.11
ACLOCAL_PATH: /usr/local/share/aclocal
PATH: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_66.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/shims/super:/usr/local/opt/ant/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

**Any tips how to get buck running**

Comment: This might be happening because you are running an older version of Buck. If you unset all Android-related environment variables (`unset ANDROID_HOME ANDROID_SDK ANDROID_NDK`) and run `buck --version`, it should tell you what version of Buck you are running. I suspect your version does not include the commit that adds support for reading the new-style `source.properties`: https://github.com/facebook/buck/commit/7a6fba112f62abf865c27e3dd91d6e5d97625d95.

Comment: when i remove all ndk variables, i get `buck version v2016.03.28.01`. how can i update it via brew?

Comment: Hm, it looks like the version available in brew is a bit outdated. I will check what we need to do to update it. In the meanwhile you can try using the latest version from GitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost definitely caused by the version of Buck available from Homebrew being too old. You can install the latest development version of Buck by running `brew rm buck && brew install --HEAD buck`, it should fix the issue.

This GitHub issue is tracking updating Buck from Homebrew to a more recent version: https://github.com/facebook/buck/issues/835.